# Number of ways of tiling a 3*N board with 2*1 dominoes problem

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, dynamic-programming, tiling

I came across this problem,
 [Tiling with Dominoes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tiling-with-dominoes/)
and initially I faced difficulty in understanding the logic behind recurrence relation, but after reading it from [here](https://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_10918) , I understood it. But I had a doubt, why aren't we considering the below cases for the above problem?

In the solution only these cases are mentioned,

```
********   AA*******   AA******   A*******
******** = BB******* + B******* + A*******
********   CC*******   B*******   BB******
  f(n)   =  f(n-2)   +  g(n-1)  +  g(n-1)
```

But my question is there can be other case as well, like below, why aren't we adding them, because the problem asks for the number of possible cases-

```
********   AA*******   AA******   A*******   AB******   CC******
******** = BB******* + B******* + A******* + AB****** + AB******
********   CC*******   B*******   BB******   CC******   AB******
  f(n)   =  f(n-2)   +  g(n-1)  +  g(n-1)  +   f(n-2) +  f(n-2)
```

Why aren't we adding them? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two cases are already counted in the recursive calls `g(n-1)`.

```
A****
A****
BB***
g(n-1)
```

`g(n-1)` counts all possibilities to fill the empty space in this ^ form. One way would be to fill it out like the following image, so this case already gets counted and you don't need to add another recursive call.

```
AC***
AC***
BB***
```